# KRPANO player for dynamic content

Tags: virtual-reality, webvr, google-vr, krpano

I have website where user can upload 360 image and video . I play that image and video using vrview but vrview doesnot seems that good as it lack enough control button in video player (as i know).

I want to use krpano , but i dont know hoe to use for dynamically added content .

I search it but couldn't get proper knowledge on that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting so anyone who will come here searching for solution could get some help :

Actually the solution comes from how video is played by krpano .

In krpano for playing video we need to give xml file that contain necessary information related to video we are going to play .

So for every video , we want to play ,  we should have xml file of that video mean xml file containing the video source , thumbnail source specified .

we can create xml file for every video file while uploading .

I made xml file using string concatenate and wrote that in xml .

xml file is in sample code inside example folder .